# How to test await block logic in Svelte with Jest

Tags: asynchronous, jestjs, svelte

This is my first attempt at writing unit tests for a Svelte app. The below example is based on the standard Svelte template with an additional

element added. In this element I conditionally render some text with await block logic.

```
<script land="ts">
  import { asyncthing } from "./asyncthing";
  import { onMount } from "svelte";

  export let name: string;

  let isReady: Promise<boolean> = asyncthing().then((resolveTo) => {
    console.log("asyncthing resolved");
    return resolveTo;
  });
</script>

<main>
  <h1 data-testid="greeting">Hello {name}!</h1>
  <p>
    Visit the <a href="https://svelte.dev/tutorial">Svelte tutorial</a> to learn
    how to build Svelte apps.
  </p>

  <p data-testid="async">
    {#await isReady}Awaiting...{:then value}Resolved to: {value}{/await}
  </p>
</main>

<style>
  main {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;
    max-width: 240px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  h1 {
    color: #ff3e00;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 4em;
    font-weight: 100;
  }

  @media (min-width: 640px) {
    main {
      max-width: none;
    }
  }
</style>
```

The function `asyncthing` returns a `Promise<boolean>` that resolves after 5 seconds with `true`.

```
export const asyncthing = async () => {
  console.log("asyncthing() called");
  return new Promise<boolean>((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("timeout expired");
      resolve(true);
    }, 5000);
  });
};
```

Opening the app in a browser works as expected, but the test below fails.

```
import App from "./App.svelte";
import { render } from "@testing-library/svelte";
import { tick } from "svelte";
import * as asyncthings from "./asyncthing";

test("messing with async", async () => {
  jest.setTimeout(20000);
  jest.useFakeTimers();
  jest.spyOn(global, "setTimeout");
  const asyncthingMock = jest.spyOn(asyncthings, "asyncthing");
  const app = render(App, { name: "Everybody" });
  expect(app.getByTestId("greeting")).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(app.getByTestId("greeting")).toHaveTextContent("Hello Everybody!");
  expect(app.getByTestId("async")).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(app.getByTestId("async")).toHaveTextContent("Awaiting...");
  expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(expect.any(Function), 5000);
  jest.runAllTimers();
  await tick();
  expect(app.getByTestId("async")).toHaveTextContent("Resolved to: true");
});
```

The log statements are printed, so the promise does seem to resolve. However, according to Jest the text is not updated. I'm sure I must be doing something wrong, so please, somebody set me straight.

Comment: I'm fighting this too. Were you able to solve this?